# IF function between 2 dates

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have created a document, which contains different tabs.
I need to enter a date of birth in one tab, then have an IF function to return certain text if that date falls between 2 dates.

For example I have tried:

=IF(B3>=Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!B1, "Summer 2024",)

So B3 is the cell with the date of birth, sheet1 A1 is the start date and Sheet1 B1 is the end date, then the wording I want it to return in the "". However it won't work! I can't figure out what to change to make it work!

Comment: `=IF(AND(B3>=Sheet1!A1,B3<=Sheet1!B1),"Summer 2024","Alternate Result")`